# Populate Django DB with local JSON file

Tags: python, json, django

I create a web application with Django and I need basic data. To do this, I have a JSON that contains a lot of data that I would like to import into my Django database.

So I'm looking for a way to import this data without modifying the JSON file.

**Extract from JSON:**

```
[
  {
    "key": "sword",
    "name": "Sword",
    "tier": 1
  },
  {
    "key": "bow",
    "name": "Bow",
    "tier": 1
  },
...
]
```

My file contains a lot of data and it would take a long time to change it.
Is there a script / program to import all this data corresponding to the following model:

```
from django.db import models

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    tier = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

I saw the example on the [django site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/initial-data/), but it would be necessary to add to each item in my JSON a property model which would be very long

**Example from Django website:**

```
[
  {
    "model": "myapp.person",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Lennon"
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "myapp.person",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
      "first_name": "Paul",
      "last_name": "McCartney"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a custom management command to import your custom JSON file. [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/).

```
import json
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from myapp.models import Item

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('json_file', type=str)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        with open(options['json_file']) as f:
            data_list = json.load(f)

        for data in data_list:
            data['pk'] = data.pop('key')
            Item.objects.get_or_create(pk=data['pk'], defaults=data)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this is very useful. Is there a particular place where the json file should go? Or would you simply specify the directory in the place where it says `['json_file']`

Comment: Sure, no problem. Yeah you can just specify the absolute path or the path relative to the `manage.py`. So assuming your management command file is called `import_custom_stuff.py` you can run this from you project root directory:
`python manage.py import_custom_stuff path/to/file.json`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom migration file and parse/save data to db by yourself. Here is a sample migration file:

```py
# your_custom_migration.py
import json
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations
from django.core.management import call_command

def load_file(apps, schema_editor):

    YourModel = apps.get_model('your_app', 'YourModel')

    with open('data.json') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        for p in data:
            # create YourModel object and save it to database
            your_model = YourModel.objects.create(key=p['key'], name=p['name'], tier=['tier']) 


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('manager', 'your_previous_migration_that_you_depend'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(load_file, None)
    ]
```

Then you need to run: `python manage.py migrate`.

**NOTE:** Just make sure you depen on your latest migration file in:

```py
dependencies = [
        ('manager', 'your_previous_migration_that_you_depend'),
    ]
```

Comment: I didn't understand how to do this import. Which command should I use?
Moreover I get an error with the future import